# Erro ao realizar deploy no Openshift usando meu git

Tags: jsf, maven, jenkins, openshift

Olá.
Estou tendo um problema muito estranho com a minha aplicação no openshift.

Eu criei no Openshift uma aplicação Jboss e adicionei o jenkins. 
A partir dele eu mudei a origem do código fonte para o meu repositorio no git. 
Porém eu recebo este erro no final: "Failed deployments: ./ROOT.war"

O projeto compila, mas, não realiza o deploy.

Eu tentei copiar o projeto de um local que funciona "https://github.com/openshift/kitchensink-example"
Eu cópiei todos os arquivos e funcionou certinho.
Quando eu tento adicionar algum arquivo ou adicionar, começa dar o erro de falha no deploy.
O que eu posso fazer para sanar este problema?

Obrigado

Meu repositório: 
https://github.com/afonsoaugusto/diario-online-fonte.git
https://github.com/afonsoaugusto/diario-online-source.git

segue o log:
https://gist.github.com/afonsoaugusto/6eb19da1e203ffe176b1

```
Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building remotely on appbldr (app-build) in workspace /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.Channel@1e8b1a6:appbldr
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 9d56910d598ea2718e46a619deab4dcb8ea3855f (origin/master)
Checkout:repo / /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1dd6242
Wiping out workspace first.
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/afonsoaugusto/diario-online-fonte.git
Commencing build of Revision 9d56910d598ea2718e46a619deab4dcb8ea3855f (origin/master)
Checking out Revision 9d56910d598ea2718e46a619deab4dcb8ea3855f (origin/master)
[repo] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4760777020857082047.sh
+ source /usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk
++ '[' false == true ']'
++ OO_BASH_SDK=true
+ alias 'rsync=rsync --delete-after -azS -e '\''/usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh'\'''
+ upstream_ssh=550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com
+ rm -f /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a//app-deployments/current/metadata.json
+ marker_present force_clean_build
+ '[' -f /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/markers/force_clean_build ']'
+ set +e
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_BUILD_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh '550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:$OPENSHIFT_DEPENDENCIES_DIR' /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ set -e
+ gear build
Building git ref 'origin/master', commit 9d56910
Found pom.xml... attempting to build with 'mvn -e clean package -Popenshift -DskipTests'
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232336; 2012-12-18 14:36:37-0500)
Maven home: /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building app 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ app ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ app ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ app ---
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ app ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ app ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ app ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ app ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [app] in [/var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/target/app]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [313 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/deployments/ROOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF/web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.755s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 20 19:28:33 EDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com 'gear stop --conditional --exclude-web-proxy --git-ref 9d56910d598ea2718e46a619deab4dcb8ea3855f'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
fatal: not a tree object
Stopping gear...
Stopping jbossas cartridge
++ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com 'gear create-deployment-dir'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ deployment_dir=2015-03-20_19-28-37.035
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a//app-deployments/current/metadata.json 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:app-deployments/2015-03-20_19-28-37.035/metadata.json
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh --exclude .git /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/repo/ 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/repo/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/ 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/build-dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ rsync --delete-after -azS -e /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh /var/lib/openshift/550ca7224382ec451900014a/app-root/runtime/dependencies/ 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com:app-root/runtime/dependencies/
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ /usr/libexec/openshift/cartridges/jenkins/bin/git_ssh_wrapper.sh 550b287c4382ecebeb000090@app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com 'gear start'
Warning: Permanently added 'app-diarioescolar.rhcloud.com,10.97.150.145' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Starting gear...
Starting jbossas cartridge
Found 127.5.118.1:8080 listening port
Found 127.5.118.1:9999 listening port
/var/lib/openshift/550b287c4382ecebeb000090/jbossas/standalone/deployments /var/lib/openshift/550b287c4382ecebeb000090/jbossas
CLIENT_MESSAGE: Artifact: ./ROOT.war is still deploying
/var/lib/openshift/550b287c4382ecebeb000090/jbossas
Failed deployments: ./ROOT.war
Archiving artifacts
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Consegue colocar a saida do log do jboss no post?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/afonsoaugusto/6eb19da1e203ffe176b1 - O log é a saída que eu tenho na compilação do jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Cara, aparentemente depois que é feito o build da sua aplicação o ROOT.war não está sendo copiado para a pasta do JBoss, pode-se confirar um plugin no maven que faça isso automaticamente depois feito o build com sucesso.